# pyspark - insert generated primary key in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a dataframe and for each row, I want to insert this row in postgres databases and returning the generated primary key in this dataframe. I don't find a good way to do this.

I'm trying with rdd but it doesn't works ([pg8000 get inserted id into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485564/pg8000-get-inserted-id-into-dataframe))

I think it is possible with this process :

- loop on dataframe.collect() in order to process the sql insert
- make a sql select for a second dataframe
- join the first dataframe with the second

But I think this is not optimized.

Do you have any idea ?
I'm using pyspark in aws glue job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only things that you can optimized are the data inserting and connectivity.

As you mentioned that you have totally two operations, one is the data inserting and another one is to collect the data inserted. Based on my understanding, either spark jdbc or python connector like `psycopg2` will not return the primary key of the data that you inserted. Therefore, you need to do it separately.

Back to your question:

1. You don't need to use the for loop to do the inserting or `.collect()` to convert back to python object. You can use spark-postgresql jdbc to do it directly with dataframe:

   > ```
   > df\
   >     .write.mode('append').format('jdbc')\
   >     .option('driver', 'org.postgresql.Driver')\
   >     .option('url', url)\
   >     .option('dbtable', table_name)\
   >     .option('user', user)\
   >     .option('password', password)\
   >     .save()
   > ```